# VBA Variable with predefined values

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

Is it possible to create a variable with a predefined value list?

```
Public {VariableName} As {"Opt1", "Opt2", "Opt3"}
```

... so that, when I use this variable it automatically suggests the values?
In VBA we have the following "settings" (I haven't found the correct name of these properties, but in this example I'm using property "VbMsgBoxStyle"):

[image]

Other example is in Outlook Busy Status' list.
[image]

What is the correct name of these property members? How can I create custom list?
[image]

The idea is to make these developments easier by not having to write down in a notepad the values that we use for validation.